# how implement the jqueryUI in visualforce

Tags: visualforce

Ill implement the some UI but its not working in the visualpage , can u know how implement jquery ui in viusalpage ,

Kindly tell the procedure ,

http://jungleeforce.wordpress.com/2013/05/05/using-jquerys-autocomplete-in-salesforce-part-1/

Im using this url its not working ,,,,,

Comment: There's not enough detail. Are you getting some sort of error? Have you tried tracing through the JavaScript? Can we see your non-functioning code? Does it work only in certain browsers? More detail is better.

Comment: So you copied that VF page exactly into your own org, and then when you go to the page what happens? Tell us what you mean by "not working"

Comment: if you're using chrome, then make sure that you read the PS mentioned in the post

Answer (score 5):

I have this working on my [Developer Edition](http://matthewkeefe-developer-edition.na8.force.com/jQueryAutocompleteRemoteAction).

Apex Class:

```
global class ContactServices
{   
    webservice static List<Contact> FindContact(string ContactSearchTerm)
    {
        List<List<sObject>> searchList = [FIND :ContactSearchTerm RETURNING Contact (Id, FirstName, LastName, Email)];
        return searchList[0];
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" id="ContactAutocompletePage">

    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" />
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" />
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/18.0/connection.js" />
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/18.0/apex.js" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
    </script>

    <apex:stylesheet value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <style>
        body
        {
            font-family: arial, helvetica,sans-serif; 
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        // this is needed because Salesforce uses another JS library
        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

        j$(document).ready(function(){
            init();
        });

        function init()
        {
            sforce.connection.sessionId = __sfdcSessionId;

            j$("#FindContact").autocomplete(
            {
                source: function(request, response){response(findContacts(request.term));},
                minLength: 1
            });
        }

        function findContacts(searchterm)
        {

            var result = sforce.apex.execute("ContactServices", "FindContact", {ContactSearchTerm:searchterm});

            var mappedresult = j$.map(result,
                function(item, index) {
                    return {
                        label:item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName, value:item.Id
                    }
                }
            );

            return mappedresult;
        }

    </script>    

    <apex:form id="ContactForm">
        <h1>jQuery Autocomplete With the Force.com Ajax API</h1>
        <p>
            Contact Autocomplete: <input type="text" id="FindContact"></input><br/>
            <span>Try "Barr", "Song", or "Jack"</span>
        </p>
        <p><br/></p>
        <p>
            <span>Documents</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/">jQuery UI Autocomplete</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/index.htm">Force.com Ajax API</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_calls_sosl.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_calls_sosl.htm|SkinName=webhelp">SOSL</a></li>
            </ul>
        </p>
        <p><br/></p>
        <p>
            <span>Source</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{!$Resource.jQueryAutocompleteWithSFAjaxAPI}">Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="{!$Resource.ContactServices}">Controller</a></li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: If you changed this to a @RemoteAction, you'd stop eating up API calls. Nice solution, though.

Comment: Here's a post I wrote a long time ago about an AutoComplete component. [http://www.verticalcoder.com/2011/02/19/salesforce-javascript-remoting-jquery-and-autocomplete/](http://www.verticalcoder.com/2011/02/19/salesforce-javascript-remoting-jquery-and-autocomplete/)

Comment: Using this url its working , but ill use to static resource its not working -